# Can't see query history in Firebase (using Axios)

Tags: firebase, logging, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I'm using Axios in a React application to query a firebase database (realtime) like this:

```
axios.get("/messages.json", 
          { params : { messageType : "incoming" } } )
```

Querying the messages table without params works fine, but when adding the params it doesn't filter the results.

I would like to see a history of my queries in Firebase, hopefully it will help me understand why using params does not work.

When looking in the Firebase dashboard in the Logs tab (Functions section), it says that were no logs for this project, although I added/removed/fetched data many times.

[image]

Do I need to setup something on Firebase side?
or in my application / on Axios?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how what you're describing would show in in the Cloud Functions logging. Can you edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the question

Comment: Where is the code making your `axios.get` call running? The `Functions` > `Logs` panel only shows logging from code that runs in Cloud Functions.

Comment: OK. My bad. I thought that it's relevant to realtime database as well (if it's not relevant, why they show it in the 1st place???). So, with Firebase realtime database, you can't view query logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Functions` > `Logs` panel in the Firebase console only shows output from your code that runs in Cloud Functions. If you're running this code anywhere else, it won't show up on that place.

There is no place in the Firebase console to see all queries or other operations, except for the counters in the usage Usage panel. If you want to know all the query, you'll have to add logging yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As Frank mentioned, Firebase logging doesn't automatically log outgoing/incoming HTTP calls.

You can use Axios interceptors to add your own logging. https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors